# Display all music on SD card

Tags: android, listview, sd-card

I'm using code form this page:

http://z4android.blogspot.com/2011/06/displaying-list-of-music-files-stored.html

The code is working, but not soo good.
When I'm trying to scroll down, the ListView keeps repeating the songs in the list.

I have been looking for some alternative code, but I have not found any.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure exactly what causes the problems you mention, but try this code.

```
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
private String[] mMusicList;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

  ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

  mMusicList = getMusic();

  ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mMusicList);
  mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

  mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
    long arg3) {
      try {
        playSong(mMusicList[arg2]);
      } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  });
}

private String[] getMusic() {
  final Cursor mCursor = managedQuery(
  MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
  new String[] { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME }, null, null,
  "LOWER(" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + ") ASC");

  int count = mCursor.getCount();

  String[] songs = new String[count];
  int i = 0;
  if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
      songs[i] = mCursor.getString(0);
      i++;
    } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
  }

  mCursor.close();

  return songs;
}

private void playSong(String path) throws IllegalArgumentException,
IllegalStateException, IOException {
  String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
  .toString();

  path = extStorageDirectory + File.separator + path;

  mMediaPlayer.reset();
  mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
  mMediaPlayer.prepare();
  mMediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Comment: It causes IOException: Prepare failed. status=0x1 at the line mMediaPlayer.prepare();

Comment: Getting IOException prepare failed status=0x1!!!

Answer (score 11):

Andreas answer is the right way to do this but that code does not get the absolute file path.
This causes the `mMediaPlayer.prepare();` to throw `IOException: Prepare failed. status=0x1`.

Here is the code to get the file path along with the file name:

```
private String[] mAudioPath;
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
private String[] mMusicList;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    mMusicList = getAudioList();

    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mMusicList);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
    long arg3) {
    try {
        playSong(mAudioPath[arg2]);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
   });
}

private String[] getAudioList() {
    final Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA }, null, null,
            "LOWER(" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + ") ASC");

    int count = mCursor.getCount();

    String[] songs = new String[count];
    String[] mAudioPath = new String[count];
    int i = 0;
    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            songs[i] = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
            mAudioPath[i] = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
            i++;
        } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
    }   

    mCursor.close();

    return songs;
}
```

Now that we have the absolute path, we don't need to get the path again. So:

```
 private void playSong(String path) throws IllegalArgumentException,
    IllegalStateException, IOException {

    Log.d("ringtone", "playSong :: " + path);

    mMediaPlayer.reset();
    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);       
//mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
    mMediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Make sure to use:

```
playSong(mAudioPath[arg2]);
```

instead of:

```
playSong(mMusicList[arg2]);
```

in the listview OnItemClickListener.

To get only the title of the track (Looks more elegant than the whole file name with extension) use:

```
`MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE`
```

instead of:

```
`MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME`
```

Comment: You does not call getAudioList()

Comment: I have made an edit. Thank you! :)

Comment: How to get list of file less than some Duration?

Comment: I tried for Title one but it says column title does not exist ? . Any help would be appreciated ..

Comment: Why are you declaring String[] songs and String[] mAudioPath twice? I don't think you need to declare it again in getAudioList() method.

Answer (score -1):

The code there is super-buggy.

The `getView` doesn't make any sense. What is that gc() doing there?! What's with the all moveToPosition() calls.

Here's the code rewritten

```
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
              TextView tv = null;
              String id = null;
              if (convertView == null) {
                    tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
              } else
                    tv = (TextView) convertView;

              music_column_index = musiccursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
              id = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
              music_column_index = musiccursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE);
              id += " Size(KB): " + musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);

              tv.setText(id);
              return tv;
        }
```

Comment: "the code there" means the one by @nikos-leonov ?

Comment: Yes, the code there refers to the code by @Nikos Leonov. He has updated his answer to equal mine, so its ok now :D

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
System.gc();
String id = null;
TextView tv;
if (convertView == null) {
tv = new TextView(mContext.getApplicationContext());
} else{
tv = (TextView) convertView;
}
musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);
music_column_index = musiccursor
.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
id = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
music_column_index = musiccursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE);
id += " Size(KB):" + musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
tv.setText(id);
return tv;
}
```