# Accessing all tracks in a music player from an application

Tags: android

How can I access tracks in music player from an application in android? I have to import all tracks by somehow and play them on some other device over bluetooth connection.

Comment: Means you want to list all music files present in SD-card. Is this you want???

Comment: Yeah, and I should be able to pick and play them.

Comment: i have updated my answer. Just check whether it is working or not...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display all music on SD card](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994625/display-all-music-on-sd-card)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, use below code to get all music file inside list-view from SD-card.

```
public class Recording_List extends Activity{

    ListView mListView;
    ImageView mPlayPause;

    private File file;
    private MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

    private static final String MEDIA_PATH = new String(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/AudioRecorder/");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recordlist);

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.recordList);
        mPlayPause = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.play_pause);

        file = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdir();
        }
        File list[] = file.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            myList.add(list[i].getName());
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        mListView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                playSong(MEDIA_PATH + myList.get(position));
            }
        });

        mPlayPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    if (mp != null) {
                        mp.pause();
                        mPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (mp != null) {
                        mp.start();
                        mPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void playSong(String songPath) {
        try {
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(songPath);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

So basically above code will list all files inside list-view from SD-card folder name Audio-recorder you can specify your path over there and get your all audio file. When you click on list-view item it will play that song.

Comment: Thanks, I am getting few errors.
There is no Utilities class.
What is R.layout.custom_list_item. It is not resolved to a type. Is it xml file name?

Comment: Ok, wait i will update.

Comment: See my updated code, now you will not get any error, and you don't need Utilities class so i have removed that parameter.

Comment: Downvoters please specify reason for down voting...