# Audio displayed Not Playing Android

Tags: android, audio

I'm trying to make a simple app that can display all audio file in Listview and also can play it, but seems the codes is not working. I got the codes from [this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994625/display-all-music-on-sd-card)

Here's the code

```
@SuppressWarnings("ALL")
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private String[] mMusicList;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);

        mMusicList = getMusic();

        ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mMusicList);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                    long arg3) {
                try {
                    playSong(mMusicList[arg2]);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private String[] getMusic() {
        final Cursor mCursor = managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME }, null, null,
                "LOWER(" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + ") ASC");

        int count = mCursor.getCount();

        String[] songs = new String[count];
        int i = 0;
        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                songs[i] = mCursor.getString(0);
                i++;
            } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
        }

        mCursor.close();

        return songs;
    }

    private void playSong(String path) throws IllegalArgumentException,
            IllegalStateException, IOException {
        String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .toString();

        path = extStorageDirectory + File.separator + path;

        mMediaPlayer.reset();
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }

}
```

But this code is not playing the clicked music. What seems the problem?

**UPDATE**
Logcat

```
09-20 18:50:41.045  21397-21409/com.example.audiolist E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -2147483648)
09-20 18:50:41.047  21397-21397/com.example.audiolist W/System.err﹕ java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
09-20 18:50:41.056  21397-21397/com.example.audiolist W/System.err﹕ at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
09-20 18:50:41.057  21397-21397/com.example.audiolist W/System.err﹕ at com.example.audiolist.MainActivity.playSong(MainActivity.java:86)
09-20 18:50:41.057  21397-21397/com.example.audiolist W/System.err﹕ at com.example.audiolist.MainActivity.access$100(MainActivity.java:18)
09-20 18:50:41.058  21397-21397/com.example.audiolist W/System.err﹕ at com.example.audiolist.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:43)
09-20 18:50:41.058  21397-21397/com.example.audiolist W/System.err﹕ at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
09-20 18:50:41.059  21397-21397/com.example.audiolist W/System.err﹕ at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1139)
09-20 18:50:41.060  21397-21397/com.example.audiolist W/System.err﹕ at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2856)
09-20 18:50:41.060  21397-21397/com.example.audiolist W/System.err﹕ at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3619)
09-20 18:50:41.061  21397-21397/com.example.audiolist W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
09-20 18:50:41.062  21397-21397/com.example.audiolist W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
09-20 18:50:41.062  21397-21397/com.example.audiolist W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
09-20 18:50:41.062  21397-21397/com.example.audiolist W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
09-20 18:50:41.063  21397-21397/com.example.audiolist W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-20 18:50:41.063  21397-21397/com.example.audiolist W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-20 18:50:41.063  21397-21397/com.example.audiolist W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
09-20 18:50:41.063  21397-21397/com.example.audiolist W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
09-20 18:50:41.064  21397-21397/com.example.audiolist W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-20 18:50:41.067  21397-21397/com.example.audiolist I/SurfaceTextureClient﹕ [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5a73f850) fps:10.20, dur:1078.67, max:126.27, min:75.62
09-20 18:50:41.089  21397-21397/com.example.audiolist I/View﹕ Touch down dispatch to android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{422343b8 V.ED.... ........ 0,135-480,207 #1020014 android:id/text1}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=252.47401, y[0]=50.63977, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=253409615, downTime=253409615, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
09-20 18:50:41.089  21397-21397/com.example.audiolist I/View﹕ Touch down dispatch to android.widget.ListView{422142a8 VFED.VC. .F...... 0,0-480,732 #7f0c004d app:id/listview1}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=252.47401, y[0]=185.63977, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=253409615, downTime=253409615, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
09-20 18:50:41.090  21397-21397/com.example.audiolist D/AbsListView﹕ Touch down: touch mode = 0,mScrollY = 0,y = 185.63977,mFirstPosition = 4,mActivePointerId = 0,mDataChanged = false,adatper size = 641,this = android.widget.ListView{422142a8 VFED.VC. .F...... 0,0-480,732 #7f0c004d app:id/listview1}
09-20 18:50:41.152  21397-21397/com.example.audiolist I/View﹕ Touch up dispatch to android.widget.ListView{422142a8 VFED.VC. .F...... 0,0-480,732 #7f0c004d app:id/listview1}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=252.47401, y[0]=185.63977, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=253409678, downTime=253409615, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
09-20 18:50:41.154  21397-21397/com.example.audiolist D/AbsListView﹕ Touch up: touch mode = 0,mScrollY = 0,mLastY = -2147483648,mMotionPosition = 6,mFirstPosition = 4,mDataChanged = false,adatper size = 641,this = android.widget.ListView{422142a8 VFED.VC. .F...... 0,0-480,732 #7f0c004d app:id/listview1}
09-20 18:50:41.222  21397-21397/com.example.audiolist D/AbsListView﹕ performItemClick view=android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{422343b8 V.ED.... ........ 0,135-480,207 #1020014 android:id/text1}, position=6, id6, mChoiceMode=0, dispatchItemClick=true
09-20 18:50:41.222  21397-21397/com.example.audiolist V/Provider/Settings﹕ from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0
09-20 18:50:41.222  21397-21397/com.example.audiolist D/MediaPlayer﹕ releaseSecureFlag() mWfdReceiver: null
09-20 18:50:41.226  21397-21397/com.example.audiolist D/MediaPlayer﹕ Don't notify duration to com.example.audiolist!
```

Comment: Did it throw an exception? Could you post the log?

Comment: i'm trying it with my android phone and emulator don't have any music

Comment: Run the app on your phone, from android studio. Then you can check the log.

Comment: its not working lol `pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.audiolist
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE]`

Comment: Make sure you have enough space on your phone.

Comment: See my Update I include the Logcat now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90155/discussion-between-cylon-and-meyka-jograt).

Comment: Do u remember solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the `prepare()` failed because you haven't added read permission to your manifest.

Try to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` to your manifest file.

---

Edit. try to use file descriptor, like this:

```
File file = new File(path);
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(inputStream.getFD());
inputStream.close();
```

Comment: Could you post the model of your device?

Comment: Please log the `path` variable, and post it here.

Comment: where should i put these with my codes? sorry still new to android

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90156/discussion-between-cylon-and-meyka-jograt).