# Pick a song from sd card and play it in android

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, startactivityforresult

I have an Application in which I want to pick a song from sd card and play it using a button. But, the selected song's path is not returned back to onActivityResult(). It is always showing null. How can I get that? Any help is appreciated.

Here is my work

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    buttonChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoose);
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v.getId() == R.id.buttonChoose) {
        System.gc();
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        Uri data = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/media/audio/notifications");
        String type = "audio/mp3";
        intent.setDataAndType(data, type);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (data != null) {
            mp = new MediaPlayer();
            mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            try {
                uri = getIntent().getData();
                if (uri != null) {
                    mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri);
                    mp.prepare();
                    mp.start();

                    mp.start();
                    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            mp.release();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data is null...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you want any specific song from your device, or all song

Comment: one selected song from the songs list

Comment: why don't you store mp3 file in your resource folder and then use it

Comment: My work is to choose a song from the list and then play it :(

Comment: Ok.. means, first you r showing data in a list and then you are playing by clicking on list item.. like any music player

Comment: yes, but returned only null data

Comment: Go through this link, it will help you. [http://stackoverflow.com/a/15085432/4876386](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15085432/4876386)

Comment: are you using Samsung or HTC device for testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `uri = data.getData();` in onActivityResult instead of `uri = getIntent().getData();`

Comment: @Kapil Rajput  you saved my day Thanks  +1 vote for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check permission in AndroidManifest.xml

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: I think kapil rajput's answer is correct. If you want to get "result intent" in `onActicityResult`, use parameter `Intent data`.

Comment: Also, in my case, I use your code but can't choose mp3 files in list. So I changed `String type = "audio/mp3";` to `String type = "audio/*";`. It will be work.