# Can't get audio from external storage

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm developing a simple music player and I got stuck on a problem where I can not get the audio files from the sd card. I'm using emulator **Nexus 5X API 28** with **Android 9.0**.

As you can see I have some mp3 files in sdcard/Music

[image]

I'm trying to get songs with help of this method:

```
public void getSongList() {
        Cursor musicCursor = getContentResolver()
                .query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        if (musicCursor != null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            //get columns
            int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
            int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
            //add songs to list
            do {
                long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
                String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
                String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
                songList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist));
            }
            while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
```

The cursor is not null but it is empty as it fails on `moveToFirst()` method. I've searched a lot of posts on SO but still can not find an appropriate solution. I think I might be searching in a wrong directory because all code should work. Hope you are able to help me.

**Update**

Permission check in onCreate() in MainActivity:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);

                return;
            }
        }
```

Permissions in Manifest.xml:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Did you see this link `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994625/display-all-music-on-sd-card` ?

Comment: @VarunRaj I've tested the method used to get songs from this posts. The cursor is still empty, getCount() returns 0

Comment: Did you check the permissions?

Comment: @VarunRaj Yes, I've update the post so you can see how I use permissions

Comment: How did you put the files in the Music directory?

Comment: @blackapps Right click on Music -> Upload (you can see Music folder on screenshot)

Comment: You mean that you put them in it using Android Studio? Well then the media store does not know about those files. They are not yet scanned. Reboot the emulator. (If you know how to do that then please tell).

Comment: @blackapps That helped :) I've used Wipe Data in AVD Manager, and added mp3 files by drag and drop on emulator

Comment: You can't query them to media content resolver because they have not been indexed by the resolver yet. Query to MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external")